# com.google.api.gax.rpc.CancelledException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: The operation was cancelled

Tags: java

在调用google speech to text service 时出现：

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.CancelledException:
>   io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: The operation was
>   cancelled.

[image]

请问如何解决？

Comment: Please try to write your questions in english so that it can be easy for everyone to understand and help you.

Comment: Calling Google Speech Recognition with java, the following error occurred

Comment: What is the cause of the error?